# About strcpy() in TCPL

Tags: c, strcpy

I am reading *The C Programming Language*, and when it gets to *Character Pointers and Functions (5.5)* I get a problem.

In *5.5*, the authors showed four versions of `strcpy()`. My problem lies in the version 3:

```
/*strcpy: copy t to s; pointer version 3*/
void strcpy(char *s, char *t)
{
    while (*s++ = *t++)
        ;
}
```

There is no comparison against '\0'. And how does the termination of the loop work under such a condition?

Comment: The C language was pretty much designed to make this type of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is. The value  of the assignment statement is the value assigned. So it will be checking whether the assigned value is `0` (`'\0'`) or not which is what is expected to be done over here.

Equivalently this code boils down to (this is how it would work). Think like this - atleast once the copy will happen. So it shows us that it will be a `do-while` loop.

```
char somechar;
do {
   somechar = *t;
   *s = somechar ;
   s++;
   t++;
} while( somechar );
```

Answer (score 4):

```
*s++ = *t++
```

is equivalent to

```
(*s++ = *t++) != 0
```

which is equivalent to

```
(*s++ = *t++) != '\0'
```

Comment: So it's just an 'idiom', as the authors said?

Comment: @1MinLeft Yes [15 chars]

Answer (score 1):

In C, `if (var = expression)` means 1) assign *expression* to *var*, then 2) check if *var* evaluates to *TRUE*. The same is for `while (var = expression)`.